# How can I create multiple new instances of a model and save them to the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using the following code to attempt to import a CSV file.  However it is just saving the last object of `Fact` rather than saving each of the objects that were built.

```
Do While Not sr.EndOfStream
  Dim aFact as Fact
  Dim mArray = sr.ReadLine().Split(",")

  aFact.Name = mArray(0)
  aFact.Value = mArray(1)
  db.Facts.Add(aFact)  
End
db.SaveChanges()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a list where you save the object

```
Dim factList As New List(Of Fact) ' add the list
Do While Not sr.EndOfStream
  Dim aFact as Fact
  Dim mArray = sr.ReadLine().Split(",")

  aFact.Name = mArray(0)
  aFact.Value = mArray(1)
  factList.Add(aFact) ' put fact object in list  
End
```

Comment: sorry not following. What am I doing with the list after I've built a collection of the Fact objects? Also since I'm using a list do I not need to use this line from the question: `db.Facts.Add(aFact)` ? Thanks

Comment: you do not need `db.Facts.Add(aFact)` .. all objects made are now in the list.. what are you trying to achieve with all the Fact objects? see the edited code

Comment: I'm attempting the changes you've shown above and then I'm calling the db.SaveChanges() after the `End`, but still not getting the objects saved to my database. `db` being my database context.

Comment: ahhhh had a silly typo mistake my apologies. Thanks for the help!